# ¿Cómo hacer Pull Request a un repositorio distinto al forkeado por mí?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-fork, git-pull

Intentaré explicar de manera sensilla:

- Hice fork de **github.com/Curso/Proyecto1** en mi repositorio, y quedó como **github.com/MiUsuario/Proyecto1**
- Luego estuve trabajando y realizando commits sobre mi repo: **github.com/MiUsuario/Proyecto1**
- Finalmente, mis profesores deciden que debemos realizar un Pull Request para entregar los ejercicios. Pero no a github.com/Curso/Proyecto1 desde donde hice el fork. Sino a **github.com/Curso/Examen1** (un repositorio distinto que no posee casi archivos dentro de él)

¿Cómo hacer un Pull Request desde mi repositorio **github.com/MiUsuario/Proyecto1** al nuevo repositorio totalmente distinto **github.com/Curso/Examen1**?

Espero haberme explicado, gracias de antemano.